# about export jar file

Tags: java, android, jar

I  have  a  projectA   depenced  on     libx.jar ,  liby.jar, libz.jar    and  then  export to  ===>>  libA.jar

And I have  a projectB  depenced on  libA.jar ,  libx.jar,  liby.jar,  libz.jar     and  then  export to  an  android  apk.

Now  here is  a question.  ProjectA  and ProjectB all  depends  on libx.jar,liby.jar,libz.jar.  How  Can  I  export  libA.jar  contians  all  of  there before. And then I  only need to depence on  libA.jar  for  projectB.

How  can I   export  useful  libA.jar  for  projectB?
 It seems  not  workful  when I  try some  method . Thows" Class Def Not Found error".

Answer (score 0):

In your project you put your jar in libs folder I guess, and did you ad it to the build path ?

Comment: Yes,I  added in my build path